# Contacts, asking to Block or add to contacts

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I recently lost my phone and reloaded WhatsApp on my new phone. Now, every time when I receive a message from a contact, it asks whether it should `block` or `add to contacts`. This does not happen when I send messages to my contacts.

Comment: Do you have given permission to read `contacts`, for WhatsApp?

Comment: Which Android version of your phone?

Answer (score 1):

If Android Version Marshmallow or above, you have to give permission.

1. Go to Settings
2. Apps
3. Whatsapp
4. Tap on Permissions
5. **On** Contacts permission and check.